# How to use mean_squared_error as loss with sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score()

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, loss-function

I can use "categorical_crossentropy" as loss function without error but when I replace it with "mse" this error raises:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

If I use the following method

```
labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes = 2)
```

another error raises:

> Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'multilabel-indicator' instead.

The question is how can I use "mse" with cross_val_score() function?

This is  [github link](https://github.com/J-Thunderbolt/Coursework/blob/master/Xception_5_Fold.ipynb) and this is the troublesome code:

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=customXceptionBuild, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=True, random_state=random_state)

def classification_report_with_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred):
    originalclass.extend(y_true)
    predictedclass.extend(y_pred)
    return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred) # return accuracy score

scoring = make_scorer(classification_report_with_accuracy_score)

scores = cross_val_score(model, data, labels, cv=kfold, error_score="raise", scoring=scoring )
```

customXceptionBuild function implements Xception pre-trained model and uses "mse" as loss function.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is about output size mismatch,
change this

```
F3 = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(D2)
```

to

```
F3 = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(D2)
```

Since this is a binary classification, you only need 1 neuron.

Or if you want to fix the second error, here is why. It is not possible to do stratification on one-hot encoded labels. You can do one hot encoding after stratification. Thus,

```
labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes = 2)
```

should come after

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=True, random_state=random_state)
```

Comment: thx but how does it work with "categorical_crossentropy"? If I remove "labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes = 2)" line it works.

Comment: It works with categorical_crossentropy, because it is for multiclass problems. What is your problem type? Binary or multiclass? It is better to read the theory first before delving to programming.

Comment: It is multiclass problem as I mentioned. You said it is binary classification!